# SQL Server - SELECT DISTINCT depending on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I got a table like this, and there's on input parameter RevParam:

```
Key Rev IsCurrent
=====================
abc 0   TRUE
def 0   TRUE
ghj 2   FALSE
ghj 0   TRUE
klm 0   TRUE
def 1   FALSE
abc 1   FALSE
abc 2   FALSE
```

Where I want `Key` to be a unique value. If `RevParam` is set all rows with that Rev value should be viewed, the missing `Key` should have: revision 0. Like this:

```
Result if RevParam = 1      

abc 1   FALSE
def 1   FALSE
ghj 0   TRUE
klm 0   TRUE

Result if revisionParameter = 0     

abc 0   TRUE
def 0   TRUE
ghj 0   TRUE
klm 0   TRUE
```

This has been buggering me all day, please help me out!

Comment: please more elaborate concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  [key], [rev], [IsCurrent],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [key]
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN [rev] = 1          -- <<== change REV value here
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) rn
    FROM    tableName
    WHERE   [Rev] IN (1,0)
)
SELECT  [key], [rev], [IsCurrent]
FROM    records 
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo for `1`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b500/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo for `0`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b500/3)

Comment: +1 I think there should probably also be a `where` clause inside the CTE - something like `where rev in (0,1)` - since the OP doesn't want to return `rev` values other than 0 or the selected value.

Comment: @MarkBannister I agree but the OP did not mention about records to show if it doesn't match on the `rev`. for example the `rev` i'm finding is `2`, there is no record for `def`, i don't know what the OP wants to show then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Mark-Bannister is correct, I only want to return Rev values that is either 0 or the revParam value. But only one type of Key can be shown. If there's no match it should return the same result as if the parameter is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Result if RevParam = 1

abc 1   FALSE
def 1   FALSE
ghj 0   TRUE
klm 0   TRUE

it has rev value 0 as well as 1. Please specify clearly